# all that vs that all

Tags: phrase-usage

Which of the options is right?

> Sorry, we don't understand __ you have said means.
>
> A. all what
>
> B. what all
>
> C. all that
>
> D. that all

I choose `C`,but my teacher says `D` is right, which I can't understand.

Comment: You're both wrong -- only B is acceptable. Even that would be better with *say* in simple past, and even better would be *We don't understand what you mean*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is the correct answer.

This sentence starts with the subject and verb

> We don't understand

The rest of the sentence must express the object of the verb - the thing that is not understood. The object of 'understood' must include the verb 'means'. The word order, with the verb 'means' at the end, indicates that the object is an indirect question, so it must start with a question word 'what'. The equivalent direct question would be

> What does all you said mean?

But since this is a subordinate clause the auxiliary verb 'does' isn't used.

> ... what all you said means

[Subordinate Clauses of Indirect Questions](http://www.english-for-students.com/subordinate-clauses-of-indirect-questions.html)

Comment: Is `all you said` equivalent to `all that you said`? I ask this because `all you said` confuses me.

Comment: Yes, it is. English is confusing, I know!

Comment: They both mean the same thing. Sometimes we use one and sometimes the other but I can't tell you how we choose one or the other.